# Grails deprecated

Tags: grails, jenkins-plugins, grails-plugin

We are upgrading Cloudbees from 2.204.2.2 to at least 2.289.2.3
Told by CB that Grails1.7 is deprecated with no alternative suggested. Does anyone have an alternative or workaround after the upgrade?

Comment: "Told by CB that Grails1.7 is deprecated with no alternative suggested." - I don't think we ever released a Grails 1.7.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown There is a very old branch [GRAILS-6737-Groovy-1.7.5](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/tree/GRAILS-6737-Groovy-1.7.5) but no release tag for _v1.7...._.

Comment: I see now.  You are talking about Groovy 1.7, not Grails 1.7.  Luke's commit comment indicates Grails 1.7 but if you look at the actual code, there is no Grails 1.7.

Comment: When I'm checking installed plugins there is in fact a Grails: 1.7 installed. This is listed by CB that it is "No longer distributed" I don't have a lot of jobs using it, but enough that I'd like to offer an alternative to the users. CB doesn't list one. Anyone have any ideas? Even if it isn't an alternative to ver 1.7?

Comment: "When I'm checking installed plugins there is in fact a Grails: 1.7 installed" - I don't think there is such a thing as Grails 1.7.  You may be looking at a version of the plugin, which is not something that we maintain and I am not familiar with their versioning scheme.

Comment: Look at the latest commit on the branch you linked.  https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/da458e78ee838da24380cc924b22693c23b19c48 - All of the 1.7 mentions there are related to Groovy.  The Grails versions in that commit all look like 1.3.

Comment: Sorry. Looking back at my original question I didn't specify that this is a plugin for Cloudbees. The plugin is grails1.7 and in all of our jobs it is basically a call to Gradle. Trying to get an answer from our developers that maybe they could call to Gradle directly without using grails, but no definite response yet. 
Thanks for your time. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

See Juan Camilo Marín's answer at [Grails plugin not available in new Jenkins versions?](https://groups.google.com/g/jenkinsci-users/c/dBtrJCjNU-0#c42):

> The plugin is not available because the new version of Jenkins may not be safe to use it, as you can see it the plugin is a bit old, the latest updated was in 2013,  so what you need to do is manually install it, you only need to copy the gradle.jpi from the old "/jenkins-installation-path/plugins" directory to the new one and then restart jenkins, then you can disable it the "Arbitrary code execution vulnerability" security warning in jenkins "configure global security" option.

Comment: Any ideas on an alternative?

Comment: @TimothyMoore You wrote in your Q: "_Told by CB_". How did the tell you? Is there some web page where this can bee seen?

Comment: I can't post a screenshot, but they did a review of our environment and gave us a list of plugins that might be a problem after upgrade. The only plugins we use on production is dynamicparameters which the gave an alternate of "Active Choices" and Grails1.7, but no alternative. Trying to find an alternative.